# Why am I not reaching inside the while loop in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, semaphore

I have the following code as an attempt to a leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately problem:

```
from threading import Semaphore
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.semFoo = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.semFoo.append(Semaphore(0))
        self.semBar = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.semBar.append(Semaphore(0))
        self.fooCount = 0
        self.barCount = 0
        print("releasing semFoo[0]")
        self.semFoo[0].release()
        
        
    def foo(self, printFoo: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        print("fooCount is " + str(self.fooCount) + " " + str(self.n))
        while self.fooCount < self.n:
            print("foocount is" + self.fooCount)
            if not self.semFoo[self.fooCount].locked():
                print("foo " + self.fooCount)
                printFoo()
                self.semBar[self.barCount].release()
                self.barCount += 1
                

    def bar(self, printBar: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        print("barCount is " + str(self.barCount) + " " + str(self.n))
        while self.barCount < self.n:
            with self.semBar[self.barCount]:
                print("bar " + self.barCount)
                printBar()
                self.semFoo[self.semFoo].release()
                self.semFoo += 1
```

The idea is to create two lists of semaphores and to release those semaphores alternatively. However, none of the code inside the while loop of both foo and bar is being executed. Even though self.fooCount < self.n, as seen the the print statement above the while loop, the print statement inside the while loop isn't printing. How to fix this?

Comment: First of all you are concatenating in print("foocount is" + self.fooCount) string with integer. You have three prints with error. 
In addition if you do dir(Semaphore) you will not find the locked() method.

Answer (score 0):

what code do you use to try and run your program ?
I tried it and I get inside the while loop, however there's an error in it, maybe that's why it doesn't get in by throwing an error you don't see before.

first in your while loop you have `print("bar " + self.barCount)` your'e trying to concatenate a string with an int so i suggest you do `print("bar " + str(self.barCount))` instead

Then threading.Semaphore doesn't have a `.locked()` method so it will also throw an error, maybe you should search this way

fianlly there's a tiny mistake in the last line `self.semFoo += 1` , I guess it should be `self.fooCount += 1`

Hope it helped you :)